# Error oauth2client.HttpAccesTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT signature

Tags: python, http, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to access my google sheets via `gspread` and google drive API and I get this error:

`oauth2client.HttpAccessTokenRefeshError: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT signature`

I'm not sure how to fix this and copied code from a website that showed it working.

It should print all records from a sheet but it gives me an error (as shown above)

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.